# Отсутствует перевод слова "Question" при проверке голосов за повторное открытие

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Отсутствует перевод слова "Question" при [проверке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/108540) голосов за повторное открытие:

> [image: question]

Судя по [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/61992667?translated=no&q=Question) непереведенного слова "Question" нет в базе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Связанный вопрос на MSE: [Review for reopen page contains non-localized word "Question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290424/339911)